# Как найти и удалить группу в регулярном выражении?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл с html кодом. Нужно найти все тэги с `style=""` и удалить `style=""`
Попробовал написать, получилось что-то подобное.

```
import re
pattern = 'style="(?P<text>[(\w;:-)]*)'
re_style = re.compile(pattern)

with open('index.html', 'r') as open_file:
    for line in open_file:
        if re_style.search(line):
            print(re_style.search(line).groups())
```

Но `style="(?P<text>[(\w;:-)]*)` ищет до первой не буквы. Для поиска текста в `style=""` хотел использовать группы, но как потом из строки удалить найденную группу?

Comment: а вот такое `style\s*=\s*"[^"]*"` и заменить на ничто? не работает?

Comment: style\s*=\s*"[^"]*" подходит. Заменять не нужно. Нужно просто удалить всё, что есть в style="".

Comment: заменить ни на что, те на пустую строку - вот и удалить. нет?

Answer (score 2):

Может кому поможет.

```
import re
import sys

def replaceLine(fileName, sourseText, replaceText): 
    file = open(fileName, 'r')
    text = file.read()
    file.close
    file = open(fileName, 'w')
    file.write(text.replace(sourseText, replaceText))
    file.close

pattern = 'style\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"'
re_style = re.compile(pattern)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as open_file:
    for line in open_file:
        if re_style.search(line):
            replaceLine(sys.argv[1], re_style.search(line).groups()[0], '')
```

Comment: Т.е. вы хотели все style удалить, а не только пустые? У вас написано, что `Нужно найти все тэги с style="" и удалить style=""` ваш же код заодно удаляет style с содержимым. Можно проще сделать код, я в ответе покажу пример

Answer (score 2):

С помощью регулярки находим и удаляем `style`:

```
content = """
<p style=""> <p style=""></p> </p>
<p style=""> <b style=""></b> </p>
<p style=" "></p>
<p style="12"></p>
"""

import re
content = re.sub('style\s*=\s*"[^"]*"', '', content)
print(content)
```

Результат:

```
<p > <p ></p> </p>
<p > <b ></b> </p>
<p ></p>
<p ></p>
```

---

Если по условию вопроса, тогда:

```
content = re.sub('style\s*=\s*""', '', content)
print(content)
```

Результат:

```
<p > <p ></p> </p>
<p > <b ></b> </p>
<p style=" "></p>
<p style="12"></p>
```